# Is Finite Field Multiplication Distributive? Moving Affine Transform in AES

Tags: aes, finite-field

In AES the output of the SubBytes step is equal to:

$a_{0-15} = d*c_{0-15}^{-1}+b$

where $d$ is a constant 8x8 matrix and b is a constant 8x1 matrix both in $GF(2)$. The inversion is done in $GF(2^8)$.

After ShiftRows the output column of each MixColumns can be expressed in terms of four select $a$ values.

$m_0 =  2a_0+ 3a_1 + a_2 + a_3$

$m_1 =  a_0 + 2a_1 + 3a_2 + a_3$

$m_2 =  a_0 + a_1 + 2a_2 + 3a_3$

$m_3 =  3a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + 2*a_3$

Is there any reason that you can't take $m_0$ for instance and write it as:

$\begin{align*}
m_0 =& 2(da_0+b) + 3(da_1+b) + (da_2+b) + (da_3+b)\\
=& 2da_0+2b + 3da_1+3b + da_2+b + da_3+b\\
=& d(2a_0+3a_1+a_2+a_3)+b\\
\end{align*}
$

This would be the MixColumns operation followed by the affine transform.

Comment: $2(da_0+b)$ is not equal to $2(da_0) + (2b)$

Comment: specifically, $b + b$ = 0, since XOR addition of a polynomial against itself is 0

Comment: @RichieFrame could you take a look at my answer

Comment: A finite field is a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)), so yes, multiplication distributes over addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above question $m = da_0$

At the bit level:

$m\oplus b = [m_7 \oplus b_7 , m_6 \oplus b_6 , m_5 \oplus b_5 , .... , m_0 \oplus b_0 ]$

$
\begin{align*}
2(m\oplus b) =& \operatorname{xtime}(2(m\oplus b)) = \\
=& [m_6 \oplus  b_6 , m_5\oplus b_5 , m_4\oplus b_4, m_3\oplus b_3 \oplus (m_7\oplus b_7), m_2\oplus b_2 \oplus (m_7\oplus b_7) ,\\& m_1\oplus  b_1,m_0
\oplus b_0 \oplus (m_7\oplus b_7),m_7\oplus b_7]\\
\end{align*}
$

Where the multiplication by $02$ is denoted $\operatorname{xtime}(x)$.

$
\begin{align*}
2m =\;& [m_6 ,m_5,m_4,m_3\oplus m_7,m_2\oplus m_7,m_1,m_0\oplus m_7,m_7]\\
2b =\;& [b_6 ,b_5,b_4,b_3\oplus b_7,b_2\oplus b_7,b_1,b_0\oplus m_7,m_7]\\
\end{align*}
$

It follows that:

$2m\oplus 2b = 2(m\oplus b)$

because they result in the same formula at the bit level. You can see a similar result for multiplication by 3.

However, the question also assumes that it is possible to convert $2da_0 \oplus  3da_1 \oplus  da_2 \oplus  da_3$ to $d(2a_0\oplus 3da_1 \oplus  da_2 \oplus  da_3)$ this is not possible because it would require the original to be written as $d2a_0 \oplus  d3a_1 \oplus  da_2 \oplus  da_3$ but matrix multiplication is not  commutative.

Comment: See page 53 of http://jda.noekeon.org/JDA_VRI_Rijndael_2002.pdf just a short hand for left shift one XOR the primitive polynomial